# How to remove background from newly created custom layout

Tags: android, layout

I have recently moved to new PC, and downloaded last version of Android Studio.

Now when I want to create custom layout and use it in my project, it appears like this:

[image]

Earlier, when I create layout, it has dark, gray background, and I can see well what is going on if I have white Image view  or something. How can I solve this?

My layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can just set background for a view you want, using `android:background` attribute.

2) You can select another theme in Android Studio interface designer or specify necessary attributes for you default app theme in file `values/styles.xml`.

There was just two obvious suggestions, your question should have more details in order to answer it.